# jQuery append add just one row

Tags: jquery, append

I have next javascript function

```
function openWindow(a,b){
$("#windows").append('<span id="window_frame">'+a+'</span>');
}
```

and when I try to use it with multiple `<a>` tags like this

```
<a onClick="openWindow('a','b');">One</a>
<a onClick="openWindow('c','d');">Two</a>
```

It adds just one span, others can't...Why ?

Edit: Actually, I'm making `<a>` tags in php while loop

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get anything in the console? I think you cannot have more than one tag with the same ID

Comment: I'm not saying your code is correct, but it does not expose the problem you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/MKrrV/. In order to get help, you have to provide more information and should provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example which actually demonstrates the problem you are facing. For example, how do you determine whether `span`s are added or not?

Comment: Do you really need to pass b as a parameter at all?

Comment: It still does not clarify anything. Why should the way you generate the anchors be related to their click behaviour?

Comment: Thank you all , i solved it, CSS was the problem , :)

Comment: Then you might as well just delete this question...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that you must use id attribute only once.

You can replace it by a class attribute.

```
function openWindow(a,b){
    $("#windows").append('<span class="window_frame">'+a+'</span>');
}
```

It can help for futur problems.